# Objective-C consecutive format specifiers printing 0

Tags: objective-c, primitive-types, format-specifiers

This is a little problem I am having, and although it seems to be basic and simple I cannot find it out, here is the code:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    unsigned long long ep  = 2292674165ul;
    unsigned long long ep2 = 2487148347ul;
    NSLog(@"%u", ep );
    NSLog(@"%u", ep2);
    NSLog(@"%u %u", ep , ep2);
    // a last try..
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u %u", ep , ep2]);
}
```

Its output:

```
2013-02-14 13:26:15.968 FTPTests[5274:1307] 2292674165
2013-02-14 13:26:15.970 FTPTests[5274:1307] 2487148347
2013-02-14 13:26:15.971 FTPTests[5274:1307] 2292674165 0
2013-02-14 13:26:15.972 FTPTests[5274:1307] 2292674165 0
```

Can someone tell me why the second specifier is printing 0? How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it worked for me....
2013-02-14 09:35:36.474 untitled.out[3522:707] 2292674165
2013-02-14 09:35:36.475 untitled.out[3522:707] 2487148347
2013-02-14 09:35:36.476 untitled.out[3522:707] 2292674165 2487148347
2013-02-14 09:35:36.476 untitled.out[3522:707] 2292674165 2487148347

Comment: Try `%lu` -- the long-longs take two parm positions in some implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `%llu` instead of `%u`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked.Something to note is that I was running the program with the i386 architecture. When I executed it as x86_64, the code I had worked perfectly. (Using %llu works well in both archs).

Comment: If you need to use just NSInteger, general recommendation from Apple for writing universal code for x86_64 and i386 would be: NSLog(@"NSInteger variable: %ld", (long)nsintegerVariable);

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're using the incorrect format specifier try using `%llu`. The compilers warns you when you compile it.